# Steering with momentum

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

I'm thinking of making a RC tank that should be simple as possible. But I'm not sure how to make proper steering for the tank. I googled about tank steering and found (for me) complex solutions as dual differential steering.
Now, my question is - Is it possible to steere the tank with momentum?
Idea for project is - Left motor will power left Wheele(tracks are too complicated to design), right motor will power right Wheele. Powered Wheele are at the back. So if I want to steere the tank to the left side, right motor will be on, left will be off. Does this method Works? Should right motor go forward but left go backward?

Here is the sketch. This is sketch for rotating/steering from place.
I guess it will work fine, but what if tank moves forward/backward and wants to steere?

[image: The sketch]

Comment: There are books on track technology...

Comment: @SolarMike How does these books help me for steering?

Comment: Ok, just a hint for your research... Will you combine driving one wheel with braking the other side?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, if it will work. But that is for steering around Z axis, without moving the tank forward or backward.

Comment: Which other axis are you steering around? X or Y?

Comment: Just edited comment.

Comment: If the tank moves forward is it steering around the X, Y or Z axis?  And what about in reverse?

Comment: Around Z axis. For reverse just spin the motors in reverse directions. I'll add the sketch in question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skid-steer_loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to either use swivel pivot on the front wheels like shopping cart front wheels, or place the CG of your toy near the rear end.

Or else the steering will not be very effective.

If you do that by applying different power to left or right rear wheels you get turned to right or left.

If you watch delivery fork lifts of say Home Depot, you see they can maneuver precisely into tight corner. Their front wheels are free to pivot. And back wheels are attached to a joy stick.

Comment: What is CG? I don't understand that

Comment: @SilvioCro, CG is center of gravity. Means most the weight should be on the rear wheels.

Comment: What if I put Powered wheeles in middle and one pair of wheeles at front and back of tank? So momentum goes around CG point, not offset point.
With this way, it'll work while standing still, but will it while moving? I guess Sharp turning are impossible.